# Silverlight ComboBox

Tags: silverlight, combobox

what is the name of the property to set the number of items displayed when the list pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are looking for is called `MaxDropDownHeight`.  Note this is a height in pixels not a count of items.